# Making sub website invisible to public on DNN cloud

Tags: cloud, dotnetnuke

I am using DotNetNuke platform for my website. I have to deploy my stuff on cloud.

I have one main website `www.mycompanyname.org` and a sub website (intranet) `intranet.mycompanyname.org`.

How can I make my intranet subsite on the cloud invisible to the public?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the Request filtering that DNN provide, you could limit the incoming requests to specific IP addresses, to only allow for your company's IP(s) to access.

Other than that, there isn't too much in DNN that you can do besides locking the site down and requiring a login to access any of the pages.

You could use a robots.txt file IF you have it setup as a standalone portal, but I don't think DNN supports individual robots.txt files for sites with multiple portals in one install.